# Resolving search query & API call in ReactJS weather APP

Tags: reactjs, api, search, city

I had this operational, now just blanking.. Just trying to search `weatherBit` API by city name for data below are my `onChange` and `handleSearch` (from child `onClick`) functions...

Below is my App.js component. thanks in advance.

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      response: [],
      inputVal: ""
    }
  }

  handleSearch = () => {
    getWeatherData(this.state.inputVal) //(call getWeatherData function from below)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getWeatherData = inputVal => {
      fetch(
        "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?city=Seattle,WA&key=168c5cb818e74abd926a9d65d285d48f"
      )
        .then(res => res.JSON())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({ response: data })
          console.log(data)
        })
    }

    //handleChange from WeatherQuery input:
    handleOnChange = e => {
      this.setState({ inputVal: e.target.value })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <WeatherQuery
          handleChange={this.state.handleChange}
          handleSearch={this.state.handleSearch}

    )
  }
}
export default App
```

this is my input from child component->

```
<input
          onChange={event => 
     this.props.handleChange(event)}
          name="text"
          type="text"
          placeholder=""
          value={this.state.inputVal}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

does getWeatherData have to live inside componentDidMount()?

I know why you are doing it, you want to call the function getWeatherData after it mounted. But your component is class based, so you can easily the function by using this.getWeatherData()

Same,

**ALSO**
handleSearch = () might need a Parameter

Hope that helps